# Given an array of Strings, return the number of sets of anagrams

Tags: java, strings

Please review my code:

```
public class Anagram {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] arr = { "abc", "cbc", "bcc", "dog", "god", "mary", "army",
                "rty" };
        HashMap<Integer, List<String>> mapList = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int hashcode = gethashcode(arr[i]);

            if (mapList != null && mapList.get(hashcode) == null) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                mapList.put(hashcode, list);
                list.add(arr[i]);
            } else {
                List<String> list = mapList.get(hashcode);
                list.add(arr[i]);
            }
        }

        printMap(mapList);

        System.out.println("Count=" + mapList.size());
    }

    private static void printMap(HashMap<Integer, List<String>> mapList) {

        if (mapList != null && mapList.size() > 0) {
            for (Integer key : mapList.keySet()) {
                List<String> list = mapList.get(key);

                System.out.print("[");
                if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < list.size(); k++) {
                        System.out.print(list.get(k) + " ");
                    }
                }
                System.out.print("]");
            }
        }

    }

    private static int gethashcode(String str) {
        int hashcode = 0;
        char ch[] = str.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
            if (hashcode != 0) {
                hashcode = hashcode + String.valueOf(ch[i]).hashCode();
            } else {
                hashcode = String.valueOf(ch[i]).hashCode();
            }
        }
        return hashcode;
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> [mary army ][abc ][rty ][cbc bcc ][dog god ]    Count=5
> ```

Comment: please help me with how and why you did what  you did ?I mean the algo ? how/why hashcode works here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Bug

I fed `"aad"` and `"abc"` to your program, and it considered the two strings anagrams of each other.  The problem is that you are trying to use a hashcode to determine whether two strings are anagrams of each other.  However:

1. Your hashcode is not very good because it simply adds the characters of the string together.  Therefore `"aad"` and `"abc"` were considered equivalent.
2. No matter what, a 32 bit hashcode is going to have some problems because there are more than 2^32 different anagram possibilities if you use long enough strings.  Even a 64 bit hashcode would not be enough.

I suggest that you think about creating a sorted string (i.e. alphabetized) as your hash key instead of a numerical hashcode.

### Simplification

This code:

> ```
>        if (mapList != null && mapList.get(hashcode) == null) {
>             List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
>             mapList.put(hashcode, list);
>             list.add(arr[i]);
>         } else {
>             List<String> list = mapList.get(hashcode);
>             list.add(arr[i]);
>         }
> ```

could be simplified to:

```
        List<String> list = mapList.get(hashcode);

        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            mapList.put(hashcode, list);
        }
        list.add(arr[i]);
```